Does it make sense to specify the user id in the path, if I already get it through the JWT token?
@router.get("/{id}/files")
async def get_user_files(
    id: int,
    user: UserS = Depends(get_current_user),
    user_service: UserService = Depends(user_service),
) -> UserFiles | None:
    if id == user.id:
        user_files = await user_service.get_files(user.id)
        return user_files

In this example code, I expect that the user will pass the id of the person he wants to receive, but does this make sense if I already get his id through the JWT token and then check if they converge

If you want to allow someone to fetch someone else's files, then yes, you need the id in both places.  Otherwise no.

yep, thanks, I've been thinking about that too

you can use path like /my/files. It let you a possibility to create another path /{id}/files when you need it
